# Windows Server 2016 Dockerfile install service

Tags: powershell, docker, windows-server-2016

I am attempting to install a service in a docker container on windows server2016.

Simply placing the service there and Powershelling:

```
New-Service -Name Bob -StartupType Automatic -BinaryPathName .\SVCHost.exe
```

Adds the service however in the container I get the result:

```
PS C:\Program Files\COMPANY\Repository> start-service -Name bob
start-service : Service 'bob (Bob)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service Bob on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ start-service -Name bob
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
```

I have attempted creating a user and setting the startup user credentials but same issue.

Looking at https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/manage/windows-containers/mssql-server-2016-express-windows/dockerfile shows that they use sqlexpress to do the install of the service.

Long story short...
How do I register a service in a Windows server 2016 Docker container

Comment: Try a fully-qualified path in `-BinaryPathName`. Also, the MS images use Windows Services because that's traditionally how they run in Windows. In Docker it's preferable to run your exe in the foreground and let Docker put the container in the background by running with `-d`.

Comment: YOU WERE RIGHT it was the fully Qualified name... also am aware of -d but due to complexities of bringing legacy to docker am attempting the "easy way"

Answer (score 1):

Also, look at the [Dockerfile for microsoft/iis](https://github.com/Microsoft/iis-docker/blob/master/windowsservercore/Dockerfile). The real work in the container is done in the IIS Windows Service, but the entrypoint is a binary called `ServiceMonitor.exe`. The monitor checks the Windows Service, if the Service fails the exe fails, so Docker knows the container is unhealthy.

Comment: I just saw that yes, am planning now on using that to validate service health.

Answer (score 0):

Fully qualifying the install name works. thanks @Elton Stoneman

or figured out this works too in my program

```
        public static bool Install(string serviceName, string serviceDescription, string logonUsername, string logonPassword, string exeFile)
        {
            string managementPath = @"\\.\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Service";

            ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(managementPath);
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = mc.GetMethodParameters("create");
            inParams["Name"] = serviceName;
            inParams["DisplayName"] = serviceDescription;
            inParams["PathName"] = exeFile + " -name " + "\"" + serviceName + "\"";
            inParams["ServiceType"] = ServiceType.Win32OwnProcess;
            inParams["ErrorControl"] = 0;
            inParams["StartMode"] = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
            inParams["DesktopInteract"] = false;
            inParams["StartName"] = logonUsername;
            inParams["StartPassword"] = logonPassword;
            inParams["LoadOrderGroup"] = null;
            inParams["LoadOrderGroupDependencies"] = null;
            inParams["ServiceDependencies"] = null;

            ManagementBaseObject outParams = mc.InvokeMethod("create", inParams, null);
            string status = outParams["ReturnValue"].ToString();
            return (status == "0" || status == "23");
        }
```